# Multiline template strings from ES6 into HTML not including line breaks

Tags: javascript, html

I have a large template literal in a JS file (using ES6 standards) that looks similar to:

```
let stringLiteral = `this is a large
                     string and it also 
                     has many lines in it

                     and this is a larger line break`
```

and to put it in my HTML file, I'm just using:

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = stringLiteral;
```

But, when I do this, the line breaks aren't being included in the HTML.  What do I have to do to make that happen?

Comment: `white-space: pre;`?

Comment: @elcanrs Ah awesome, thank you!  `white-space: pre-wrap;` is what I needed. :)

Comment: `stringLiteral.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')` ?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with template strings. The exact same situation would arise if you specified the string as `"this is a large\nstring..."`. By the way, I hope you know that the way you have written the string, the second and succeeding lines will have large numbers of spaces at the beginning. Also, you are not "putting it in my HTML file"; you are putting it into the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace in text nodes is collapsed by default. Use `<br />` or `<br>` for newlines or add `white-space: pre;` to the css for that element.

Comment: To say "new lines are ignored when using `.innerHTML`" is a bit simplistic. I think what you want to say is "whitespace in text nodes is collapsed by default".

Comment: or just `<br>` - the era of XML-ish html/xhtml is kind of over ;)

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this rather than innerHTML?

Comment: @CassidyWilliams white-space: pre; + textcontent might be better